# Using SetPixel32 in curve part

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm having a problem using SetPixel32 in curve part [image]

In SetPixel you can use this code and will work in curve part

```
pixels[(pixelXOffset + x) + (pixelYOffset + y) * _templateDirtMask.width] = Color.black;

_templateDirtMask.SetPixels(pixels);
_templateDirtMask.Apply();
```

But in SetPixels32 I don't know if I can use it cause blockwidth and blockheight has different values.

```
_templateDirtMask.SetPixels32(pixelXOffset, pixelYOffset, 32, 32, touchPixel);
```

Comment: I saw SetPixel32, SetPixel, SetPixels, SetPixels32 in this question, I am confused.

Comment: @shingo sorry for the confusion. As of now I'm using SetPixel to draw textures on shapes like circles, I'm trying to convert my code to SetPixel32 but my problem in this part is the blockwidth and blockheight as you can see in the edge of circle it has different x values and y values

Comment: `SetPixels` and `SetPixels32` are basically completely exchangable .. the only difference is the data type you want to work with (`Color` vs `Color32`) .. all other parameters are exactly the same for pixel position and pixel dimensions